# How to add extra files to pkgdown site?

Tags: r, pkgdown

I have a package that contains some Javascript code as well as R code.  I can use `pkgdown` to build a website hosted by Github for the R documentation in the package by setting things up properly and running

```
pkgdown::deploy_to_branch()
```

I can also use `JSDoc` to build a local website documenting the Javascript code, and place it in the `docs` directory that `pkgdown` uses, with links from the other parts.  This works locally, but the JSDoc files aren't included when I deploy it to Github using the command above.

How do I tell `pkgdown` to include the `JSDoc` files in the website it deploys to Github?

The question really has nothing to do with `JSDoc`; I can think of it as having a subdirectory of files that I want deployed along with all the files that `pkgdown` produces.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this:  I need to consider the files produced by JSDoc as "assets" to be copied into the web site.

In detail:

I can produce those files anywhere I like.  I chose to put them in a subdirectory named `.JSDoc/javascript` below the same directory where they live.

Then I need to edit the `_pkgdown.yml` file in the main directory of the package, and add a section containing

```
template:
  assets: path/to/.JSDoc
```

where `path/to` is relative to the main directory.  Notice that I don't include the second part (`javascript`) of the subdir name.

Then when `pkgdown::build_site()` or `pkgdown::deploy_to_branch()` runs, it will copy everthing in that `.JSDoc` directory into the top level of the website that it is producing.  Since I only have the `javascript` directory there, I get a top level directory in the final website named `javascript`.  I can refer to that from other `pkgdown` files.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! I am using this  idea to publish html content but not accessible from within the pkgdown framework. Like "hidden" content